# java.lang.ClassCastException, trying to have two activites using the same custom adapter

Tags: android, getview

I have two activities, `NewContact.java` and `ViewContact.java`, that I want to have using the same `custom adapter` as the two activites are very similar.

But I am getting the following error and my app crashes:

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.chris.tutorialspoint.ViewContact cannot be cast to com.example.chris.tutorialspoint.NewContact
```

I've read quite a few posts here with subjects `AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:`, `java.lang.ClassCastException`but I don't know how to adjust the answers to suit my needs.

Here's my `getView` code from my adapter. I know the problem is with the lines:

```
    viewHolder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener((NewContact) _c);
    viewHolder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener((ViewContact) _c);
```

If I delete one of the lines then the `custom adapter` works for the remaining activity but I want to have it working for both activities, `NewContact` and `ViewContact`.

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        System.out.println("getView number is :" + i + "convertView is : " + convertView);
        //we're naming our convertView as view
        //  View view = convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {

            //if there is nothing there (if it's null) inflate the view with the layout
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) _c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.phone_inflate_listview, null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            //      So, for example, title is cast to the name id, in phone_inflate_listview,
            //      phone is cast to the id called no etc
            viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            viewHolder.phone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.no);
            viewHolder.invite = (Button)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnInvite);
            viewHolder.check = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxContact);
            // viewHolder.check.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            //remember the state of the checkbox
            viewHolder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener((NewContact) _c);
            viewHolder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener((ViewContact) _c);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {

            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }
//        store the holder with the view
        final SelectPhoneContact data = (SelectPhoneContact) arraylist.get(i);
        //in the listview for contacts, set the name
        viewHolder.title.setText(data.getName());
        //in the listview for contacts, set the number
        viewHolder.phone.setText(data.getPhone());

        ////*********************

        //for every phone number in the MatchingContactsAsArrayList array list...
        for (int number = 0; number < MatchingContactsAsArrayList.size(); number++) {

            //if a phone number is in our array of matching contacts
            if (MatchingContactsAsArrayList.contains(data.getPhone()))

            {
                //if a matching contact, no need to show the Invite button
                viewHolder.invite.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                System.out.println("it's a match: phoneNumberofContact is : " + data.getPhone());
                //once a matching contact is found, no need to keep looping x number of time, move onto next contact
                break;

            }

            else {
                //if not a matching contact, no need to show the check box
                viewHolder.check.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }

        }


        viewHolder.check.setChecked(data.isSelected());



        viewHolder.check.setTag(data);

        // Return the completed view to render on screen

        return convertView;

    }
```

Comment: If both `Activity` classes implement `OnCheckedChangeListener`, then you just need one `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` call, casting `_c` to `OnCheckedChangeListener`.

Comment: Yes. That does it alright. Please post as answer and I'll gladly accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to cast that `Context` to the specific `Activity` types. The `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` method just needs an `OnCheckedChangeListener`, and if both classes implement that interface, you need only one call that casts the `Context` to `OnCheckedChangeListener`.

```
viewHolder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener((OnCheckedChangeListener) _c);
```

It might be prudent to add an `instanceof` check in the constructor to make sure the passed `Context` is indeed an `OnCheckedChangeListener`, which would have the benefits of failing sooner, and giving you the opportunity to perhaps throw an `Exception` with a more informative message.